# How to style Menu item in Ng Prime Menubar?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

i just started using ng prime, i used the p-menubar

```
<p-menubar [model]=""></p-menubar>
```

this is the component file :

```
  77
  ];
```

Everything is working fine but my question is how to style the menu bar item when added dynamically through component.ts file since i want to push the third and the last items to the end on the right of the bar and the first and second items to the left on the start ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, but the items to the right need to be reversed, for the order to be preserved, this is due to `float: right` reversing the order of elements.

Basically removed the `flex` container and used float right/left to position the elements!

styles.scss

```
p-menubarsub {
  width: 100% !important;
  .p-menubar-root-list {
    display: block !important;
    list-style-type: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    & > li:nth-child(1) {
      float: left !important;
    }
    & > li:nth-child(2) {
      float: left !important;
    }
    & > li:nth-child(3) {
      float: right !important;
    }
    & > li:nth-child(4) {
      float: right !important;
    }
  }
}
```

html

```
<div class="card">
    <p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'menubar-basic-demo',
  templateUrl: './menubar-basic-demo.html',
})
export class MenubarBasicDemo implements OnInit {
  items: MenuItem[] | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {
        label: 'First item',
      },
      {
        label: 'Second item',
      },
      {
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-power-off',
      },
      {
        label: 'third item',
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nxiyzb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fmenubar-basic-demo.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fmenubar-basic-demo.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fmenubar-basic-demo.ts,src%2Fstyles.scss)

Comment: i added the css to the scss file of my component but it still dont work

Comment: @yacinebengharsallah if you are able to modify the stackblitz replicate the issue and share it with me, I will fix it!

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution for items to end

```
::ng-deep p-menubarsub {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 60px;
}

::ng-deep .p-menubar-root-list {
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: end;
}
```